# How to fix relative urls with nginx?

Tags: html, nginx, web, url

I'm on my way to learn a bit about nginx and I've already hit a wall. I'm trying to run a small static html site which has the a very simple tree structure like below:

```
/var/www/mydomain.com/pages/category1/0.html
/var/www/mydomain.com/pages/category1/1.html
/var/www/mydomain.com/pages/category1/2.html
/var/www/mydomain.com/pages/category1/3.html
/var/www/mydomain.com/pages/category1/4.html
/var/www/mydomain.com/pages/category1/5.html
/var/www/mydomain.com/pages/category1/6.html
/var/www/mydomain.com/pages/category1/7.html
/var/www/mydomain.com/pages/category1/8.html
/var/www/mydomain.com/pages/category1/9.html
/var/www/mydomain.com/pages/category2/0.html
/var/www/mydomain.com/pages/category2/1.html
/var/www/mydomain.com/pages/category2/2.html
/var/www/mydomain.com/pages/category2/3.html
/var/www/mydomain.com/pages/category2/4.html
/var/www/mydomain.com/pages/category2/5.html
/var/www/mydomain.com/pages/category2/6.html
/var/www/mydomain.com/pages/category2/7.html
/var/www/mydomain.com/pages/category2/8.html
/var/www/mydomain.com/pages/category2/9.html
/var/www/mydomain.com/pages/category3/0.html
/var/www/mydomain.com/pages/category3/1.html
/var/www/mydomain.com/pages/category3/2.html
/var/www/mydomain.com/pages/category3/3.html
/var/www/mydomain.com/pages/category3/4.html
/var/www/mydomain.com/pages/category3/5.html
/var/www/mydomain.com/pages/category3/6.html
/var/www/mydomain.com/pages/category3/7.html
/var/www/mydomain.com/pages/category3/8.html
/var/www/mydomain.com/pages/category3/9.html
```

If I go to the urls by doing `www.mydomain.com/pages/category1/1.html` or `www.mydomain.com/pages/category2/2.html`, etc... everything will work ok, so far so good (all links fine).

Each of the html pages are using relative hrefs that looks similar to this:

```
href="../category1/0.html"
href="../category2/0.html"
href="../category3/0.html"
href="0.html"
href="1.html"
href="2.html"
href="3.html"
href="4.html"
href="5.html"
href="6.html"
href="7.html"
href="8.html"
href="9.html"
```

So it makes sense everything works when your requests are like `www.mydomain.com/pages/category1/1.html`.

Now, here's come my problem, I'd like the site to also work when somebody goes to `www.mydomain.com` so the first idea that come to my mind would be modifying the server `index` directive like this:

```
server {

    server_name mydomain.com;
    root /var/www/mydomain.com;

    index pages/category1/0.html;

    # index.html fallback
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ index.html;
    }
}
```

But if I do it that way all the links will become invalid... I mean, it'll respond valid content to `www.mydomain.com` but from there all the relative urls will be invalid.

I'm sure this is a pretty basic scenario, so could you please advice how could I solve this by modifying my above nginx configuration?

Ps. I know this could be solved much more easily probably using proper backend technology instead flat static html but I'd like to keep it as simple as possible for now so if this can be solved tweaking the nginx config that'd be great.

Answer (score 0):

Currently in order to make it to work, you have to change your configuration to:

```
server {

    server_name mydomain.com;
    root /var/www/mydomain.com/pages/category1; #this must be a path

    index 0.html;

    # index.html fallback
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```